# The existence of a one-variable version of a two variable function

Tags: functional-analysis

**The question body has updated to give more context of the problem and my intuition behind its solution**

**Intro**

I'm currently working on a learning problem in which a function $f(\textbf{x})$ has to be learned for predicting multiple tasks which I denote them by vector $\textbf{y}$. We know that each input $\textbf{x}$, corresponds to one, and only one point the space of $\mathcal{Y}$ ($\textbf{y} \in\mathcal{Y}$). In other words, there is a one to one mapping between elements of $\textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$ and $\textbf{y} \in\mathcal{Y}$.

In this specific problem, it is believed that tasks are not independent and therefore, it is easier to estimate each task knowing the value of other tasks; More formally, instead of
$$\theta = \arg \min E_{\mathcal{D}}[ (\textbf{y}-f_{\theta}(\textbf{x}))^2] $$
people look for 
$$\theta_i = \arg \min E_{\mathcal{D}}[ (y_i -f^{(i)}_{\theta}(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}_{-i}))^2]$$
where $i$ is the rask id and subscript $-i$ means all other tasks except $i$.

Although in our problem it gives accurate results under certain training methods, it needs estimation of the parameters and thus to reach a final result, it's not unusual to perform the training multiple times in an iterative fashion:

1. roughly estimate all $y_i$ and call it $y_{i,0}$.
2. train model $f_{\theta}^{(i)}$
3. find a better estimation of $y_i$, call it  $y_{i,1}$
4. repeat 2 and 3 until you converge
5. the final results are $y_{i,\infty}$

I want to avoid this iterative procedure. Since this is a physical problem and it is reasonable to assume all the dependencies, functions or probability distributions have some level of regularity. In particular, we can build a sub-model $g_i(\textbf{x})$ for predicting $y_i$. A few questions related to this are:

1. [Difference between multitask learning and transfer learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255025/difference-between-multitask-learning-and-transfer-learning)
2. [Multi-task learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24313/multi-task-learning)

**Note**: I just have linked these questions for clarifying my context. My main question is a simplified version of the problem above:

So to simplify my problem, I came up with a one-task problem:

> I have a continuous real-valued function $f(x,y) = f(x, g(x))$ and I know that $y=g(x)$. What conditions $g$ and $f$ must meet in order to ensure the existence of a function $h(x) = f(x,y)$ over a certain interval of the domain?

I believe the key point is confining the $g$ and $f$ to some class of function with some regularity property. But I don't have enough mathematical knowledge to figure that out myself. So here we are. I appreciate any help or link to the relevant theorem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for your suggestion. I did so.

Comment: What is wrong with $h : x \mapsto f(x,g(x))$?

Comment: In principle, the $g(x)$ itself is an unknown function. Learning it due to dependency of all $y$s is not easy (at least for me).